# Can't install php-imagick on Amazon Linux 2 for PHP 7.4

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, imagick, amazon-linux-2

When I try to run `sudo yum install php-imagick`

I'm getting this response:

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
299 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-imagick.x86_64 0:3.4.4-10.el7.remi.7.4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.6()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-imagick-3.4.4-10.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-imagick-3.4.4-10.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-imagick-3.4.4-10.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64 (remi-php74)
           Requires: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-pecl-imagick-3.4.4-10.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64 (remi-php74)
           Requires: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Server is on Amazon Linux 2 and PHP version is 7.4.7

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?  I have spent a few hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: @AwkDenver, not yet. Any luck?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the cleanest way I found of doing it (under PHP 7.4 on Amazon Linux AMI 2):

```
sudo yum -y install php-pear php-devel gcc ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
sudo bash -c "yes '' | pecl install -f imagick"
sudo bash -c "echo 'extension=imagick.so' > /etc/php.d/imagick.ini"
```

If you're using `php-fpm`, don't forget to restart it:

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

Comment: I tried this method with Amazon Linux AMI 2 with PHP 7.4 and it worked for my WordPress. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I finally got it working.   Here are the commands that I used.  First setup Amazon linux to use php7.4

```
sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
sudo amazon-linux-extras disable php7.2
sudo amazon-linux-extras disable lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable php7.4
```

Now install PHP and some additional libs

```
sudo yum clean metadata
# The following line may not be needed, but it was part of my script
sudo yum -y install php-cli php-pdo php-fpm php-json php-mysqlnd php-xml php-mbstring php-soap php-gd
sudo yum -y install php-pear php-devel gcc 
sudo yum -y install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel ImageMagick-perl
sudo pecl install imagick
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so
```

Add extension=imagick.so to the Dynamic Extensions section of the file.

```
sudo vi /etc/php.ini
```

Comment: You can also automate adding the extension with `echo "extension=imagick.so" | sudo tee /etc/php.d/20-imagick.ini` since the files in php.d are autoloaded. Also do not forget to restart php-fpm (if you're using fastcgi) and httpd/nginx!

Answer (score 1):

My repository is firstly designed for RHEL and CentOS.

In version **7.8**, ImageMagick was rebased to **6.9.10**, and php-pecl-imagick requires, at least, this new version.

So looks like Amazon is still late behind.

You can enable "remi" repository , which provides latest version (6.9.11-28 for now)

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php74 install php-pecl-imagick
```

For memory, this was tracked as [#144](https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues/144)

Comment: Tried that but got this error instead:

    Error: Package: ImageMagick-libs-6.9.11.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
    Requires: libraw_r.so.19()(64bit)
    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest